# What is the difference between effect and affect?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

I am confused about these two words how they differ in usage. Would be easy if explained with example.

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/315/16833

Comment: Apart from their having similar pronunciation, what leads you to confuse them?

Comment: I've voted to close this question for the time-being because it appears that this question can be answered by looking up both "effect" and "affect" in a dictionary, and such questions are off-topic for ELL. If you rephrase the question to include the definitions of both and you still have problems, the question will be reopened.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are lots of examples of usage for each sense of [affect](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/affect) ([OALD definition](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/affect)) and [effect](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/effect) ([OALD definition](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/effect)) at their dictionary definitions.

However, an interesting case appears with the following sentences.

> The UN affects changes in our foreign policy.
>
> The UN effects changes in our foreign policy.

Both sentences are valid, but have a different meaning. In the first, the meaning is that the UN *influences* planned changes in our foreign policy. In the second, the UN *initiates* changes in our foreign policy.