# Continued help understanding affect/effect

Tags: confusable

I have done this for 2 decades now. I don't think I ever want to forget this again. Because of the confusion I am continuously questioning myself on it. I know that affect influences and effect is the change.

But according to Vocabulary.com

> **effect**
>   can also be used as a verb to mean to produce or to cause to come into being.

And oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com

> **affect somebody/something**
>   to produce a change in somebody/something

So do sleeping pills affect sleep? While better mood is the effect of more sleep?

sleeping pills *affect*.
better mood is the *effect*.

Did I get this correct?

I'll deal with effect as a verb next, but I need to be able to get at least one thing right before I move on.

Comment: Please look the word(s) up before asking a question which can be answered by using a dictionary (that has to do with a meaning of some word or expression). For example, [this one](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/affect?q=affect) offers a good explanation (click on "Which Word?").

Comment: See also the similar question [What is the difference between effect and affect?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/9692/37759).

Comment: The standard advice on differentiating these terms tends to create confusion because learners encounter uses that are not addressed. *Effect* is also a verb. *Affect* is also a noun. So a sleeping pill might *effect* a change of *affect* (mood). A sleeping pill can affect affect!

Comment: [Her affect was affecting her ability to effect the best effect.](https://sciencerefinery.com/2013/07/30/her-affect-was-affecting-her-ability-to-effect-the-best-effect/) I think that link might be helpful. The sentence is a pretty good example of the different usages.

Answer (score 0):

A new answer seems suitable after the updates to the question (thanks to @NathanTuggy for those)

Note: the answers below ignore the science of pills and sleeping. They concentrate on the meaning of the 2 words, "affect" and "effect".

---

> So do sleeping pills *affect* sleep?

- Yes

---

> better mood is the *effect* of more sleep?

- Yes

It may be a better example to say:

> Sleep is the *effect* of sleeping pills.

---

> sleeping pills *affect*.

- Yes

---

> better mood is *the effect*.

- Yes

or:

> sleep is *the effect*.

---

> Did I get this correct?

- Yes

Answer (score -2):

Yes, you are correct on both counts. According to https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/effect, the most common meaning of the verb *affect* can be described as "to cause an effect".

Answer (score -2):

***Affect*** is a verb, and means: *to cause an effect*, it also means to cause an alteration in something/someone, for instance: It affected my life in many different ways.

***Effect*** is a substantive, and means the consequence of something/someone, for instance: Drinking in that party caused me many effects, I have been vomiting since then.

Comment: *Effect* can also be a verb, although it is mostly used as a noun.

Comment: @ChristopheStrobbe ...and "affect" can be a noun, even though it's mostly used as a verb. It's no surprise this word pair is so confusing.

Comment: @ColleenV You're right. I'll post my own answer in the next few days :-)